# Referencing Named Ranges in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have named several ranges in excel and would like to use them in a formula (countif). Instead of entering the formula and changing it manually all the time, I would like to reference a cell with the name of the appropriate range. For example:

`=COUNTIF(C1, A1)`

and in C1 write "Range1" or "Range 2" or "Range 3". When I try to do that, however, it doesn't seem to work.

I've also tried using the "Use in Formula" from the Formula ribbon, and pasting the named range into C1 (so that C1 now has "=Range1" for example), but that didn't work.

Does anyone know if such a thing can be done in Excel? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try it without the quotes? Something like **=countif(Range1, Range2)**

Comment: For future reference formula questions - as distinct from VBA programming questions - are better suited to Super User

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `INDIRECT` to return the string reference in C1 as the range

`=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(C1),A1)`

Debra Dalgleish's site has useful information on [INDIRECT here](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html)